# Distortion (artifacts) in android studio editor

Tags: android

Often, after switching in the xml editor from the "Code" tab to the "Design" tab and back, such distortions appear. Only in the editor window. Left side of Androyd studio without distortion. Android studio 4.1.3. On another computer (Androyd studio 3), such artifacts may also appear.

[Distorted picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk70M.png)

Only restarting the Androyd studio helps. Is it possible somehow to do without rebooting?

Comment: The latest production version of Android Studio is 4.2.2 -- have you tried it?

Comment: Updated. I didn't even hope (more than a year of torment). For two days, distortions did not appear !!! Thank you!!!